LWC Addition Assignment Operator (+=) appending
I have a lWC that is summarizing a total.  If I have a single row the Cost summary works but when a new row is added it fails because it adds a 0 to the front of the total and I am not sure why.  Its not adding the 0 to the Cost but instead appending it to the front.
JS
@track costSummary = 0;

handlePerCrewChange(event) {
let newRow = {...this.rowData};

newRow.Per_Crew__c = event.detail.value;
let dpc =  parseFloat(newRow.Per_Crew__c);
let Crew = parseFloat(newRow.Crew_Members__c) || 1;
let hours = parseFloat(newRow.Hours_Worked__c) || 1;
let worked = this.Hourly_Rate__c === undefined ? this.Rate[0].Hourly_Rate__c : parseFloat(this.Hourly_Rate__c);
newRow.Cost__c = (dpc * Crew * hours * worked).toFixed(2);
this.updateRow(newRow);
}

updateRow(rowData){
    if(!rowData){
        return;
    }
    this.rowData = {...rowData}; 
    this.handleChange();
}

handleCrewMembersChange(event) {
    let newRow = {...this.rowData};
    newRow.Crew_Members__c = event.detail.value;
    let nocm = parseFloat(newRow.Crew_Members__c)
    let crewDays = parseFloat(newRow.Per_Crew__c) || 1;
    let hoursPerDay = parseFloat(newRow.Hours_Worked__c) || 1;
    let Hoursworked = this.Hourly_Rate_LPW__c === undefined ? this.hourlyRate[0].Hourly_Rate__c : parseFloat(this.Hourly_Rate_LPW__c);
    newRow.Cost__c = (nocm * crewDays * hoursPerDay * Hoursworked).toFixed(2);
    this.updateRow(newRow);
}


saveRow(event) {
    const eventDetail = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(event.detail));
    const selectedRow = this.rows.filter(row => row.index === eventDetail.index);
    
    if(selectedRow && selectedRow.length > 0){
        const updatedRow = { ...selectedRow[0], ...eventDetail }
        this.costSummary = 0;

        this.rows = this.rows.map(row => {
            if(row.index === updatedRow.index ){
            let urc = updatedRow.Cost__c;
                 this.costSummary += urc || 0;
                return updatedRow;
            }
           //here this.costSummary  gets a 0 added to the front of the total and then throws an error
             this.costSummary += row.Cost__c; 
         
            return row;
        });  
    }

}

HTML
 <template if:true={laborTypeSpecific}>
        <lightning-layout-item size="1">
            <lightning-input name="Per_Crew__c"  class ="validateInput" label="Days per Crew" type="number" step="1" value={rowData.Per_Crew__c} onchange={handlePerCrewChange} required></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="2">
            <lightning-input name="Crew_Members__c" label="Number Of Crew Members" type="number" value={rowData.Crew_Members__c} onchange={handleCrewMembersChange} required></lightning-input>  
        <lightning-layout-item size="1">
            <template for:each={hourlyRate} for:item="hr">
                <lightning-layout-item key={hr.id}>
                    <lightning-input label="Hourly Rate" type="number" formatter="currency" step="0.01" value={hr.Hourly_Rate__c} disabled="true"></lightning-input>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </template>
        </lightning-layout-item>
        <lightning-layout-item size="1">
            <lightning-input label="Total" type="number" formatter="currency" step="0.01" value={rowData.Cost__c} disabled="true"></lightning-input>
        </lightning-layout-item>
    </template>


toFixed makes the number a string. When a number and a string are "added" together, the number is coerced to a string.
let x = 0;
let y = '123.45';
let z = x + y; // z = '0123.45'
let w = 0;
w += y; // w = '0123.45'

Make sure you're using parseFloat to ensure that you're dealing with real numbers.
this.costSummary += parseFloat(urc) || 0;

...
this.costSummary += parseFloat(row.Cost__c);


Good info @sfdcfox.  Thank you
